# how to construct a finite energy map

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions, symmetric-spaces

In the construction of harmonic maps by Eells and Sampson, one needs to start with a map with finite energy and use the heat equation to deform it into a harmonic map. The construction of such a finite energy map seems to be the starting point. I want to know if there is a systematic way to construct a finite energy map with possible singularities on the domain or on the target. To my knowledge, there is a construction in rank 1 locally symmetric space other than real hyperbolic and complex hyperbolic space by Gromov and Schoen. Also, when the rank $\ge 2$, some people require the domain to be compact to ensure the existence of this finite energy map. I am curious about more general situations, i-e other than the compact case.
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MO. Perhaps you should help out your fellow mathematicians here by recalling the definition of the energy in this very general context? You can edit your question after it is posted.

Comment: Without some requirement on the map, e.g. its homotopy class, or some equivariance, you can always just take the constant map, which has energy equal to zero.  Also, for Gromov-Schoen, those symmetric spaces are the domain, and the target is a p-adic building, and the maps are equivariant for a p-adic representation of a lattice, which is quite a bit more exotic than the Eells-Sampson work.  It might be more instructive to look for some "natural" settings where there can't be a finite energy map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is an answer but: there is a paper from 1993 ("Geometric Superrigidity") by Mok--Siu--Yeung which reproves the superridigidity results of Margulis for cocompact irreducible lattices of higher rank using differential geometric methods (harmonic maps) instead of the dynamical/ergodic theory methods of Margulis.

This differential geometric proof is available only in the case of cocompact lattices. The reason is, as far as I remember, the following: consider a nonuniform lattice $\Gamma$ of higher rank, acting on "its" symmetric space $X$ and a representation $\varrho : \Gamma \to {\rm Isom}(Y)$ where $Y$ is another symmetric space of noncompact type (we assume that $\varrho$ has large enough image, I won't give the precise statement). In that case it is not known in general how to build a $\varrho$-equivariant map of finite energy $f : X \to Y$, for a nonuniform $\Gamma$.

The "reason" is that ends of locally symmetric spaces in higher rank are harder to understand than in rank $1$... so the differential geometric proof of superrigidity currently applies only in the cocompact case. (all of this is discussed in that paper of D. Fisher page 18: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4849.pdf).

Conclusion: already for locally symmetric spaces, the problem you mention is still open in higher rank.

If you have a finite energy retraction onto a compact sets, than you will be in good shape, besides the paper of Gromov--Schoen this is also discussed in Koziarz--Maubon (Annales Fourier).